# Can I add a Russian font to the WinAPI project

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, fonts, character-encoding

I work on my own WinAPI project and use ANSI version of API language C/C++ but i have faced with the issue when I running the program on computer with non-Russian version windows. I see unreadable symbols instead of russian letters.

Can I add a Russian font to the WinAPI (GDI) project where I use non-Unicode (ANSI version)? I want to run the exe-file on a computer with non-Russian version Windows it can be displayed correctly? Or have to change the whole project under Unicode?

Comment: There are [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppLocale) [hacks](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=45) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

re

> **”** I want to run the exe-file on a computer with non-Russian version Windows it can be displayed correctly?

if you change it from ANSI based to Unicode (i.e. `wchar_t` based), yes.

then you don't have to mess with fonts either.

---

since Windows 2000 or thereabouts there has been <sup>1</sup>no reason to use the ANSI portability layer, except for legacy code

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> at the time the programs intended to also run on Windows 9x could use the Layer for Unicode, introduced in the year 2000.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app to use Unicode is best.  Windows is a Unicode-based OS, and has been for a LONG LONG time.

But, if you must stick with ANSI, then you can deploy the desired font with your app (if you have permission to do so) and use [`AddFontResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326.aspx) to temporarily install the font while your app is running, and remove it with [`RemoveFontResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162922.aspx) when the app is exited.